# 120v variable resistor controlled by 5v?

Tags: arduino, resistors, relay

I want to do some work with automating christmas lights later this year and my friend and I think relays may be the way to go. After a little more thought, I think it would be cooler if the lights could be controlled with some type of variable resistor that is "controlled" through arduino or some other low voltage source. I'm not too familiar with the vast amount of parts out there, does anything like this exist?

Comment: The power dissipation in your proposed resistor would be prohibitive. You want to PWM the lights with an isolated triac.  I don't have time to write a full answer now, but you should research triacs.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the type of lights (what kind of bulbs?) and nominal current, as this will make a difference to the options available to you.

Comment: there are actually a number of "dimmer kits" out there that would approximately do what you want, that take a low DC voltage (<12V), internally do PWM, and handle roughly that kind of load (not sure about wattage). You'd have to figure out how to get a variable voltage out of your micro-controller, to drive the dimmer kit, but that wouldn't be nearly as hard as rolling the PWM hardware/software yourself.

Comment: expanding what @Oli Glaser said -- most important here would be current or wattage

Comment: I meant incadaecent christmas lights. Set of about 50,  120v ~ .13a. dimmer kits and triacs sound like good path I guess. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what you want to accomplish with this variable resistor.  Dimming?  You should say what you want to accomplish without assuming the method.  A variable resistor is a bad idea in this case.

What it sounds like you want is called a "solid state relay".  These work pretty much like mechanical relays for your purpose, but can be switched rapidly without wearing out.  You can also get versions that turn on and off at the next zero crossing of the power line after the new control input.  That's a good idea in this case since it will cut down on radio interference generated by your setup, and generally be easier on the fillaments.

These things are switches, so are always full on or full off.  To get get a dimming effect, you switch them on and off rapidly.  For example, alternating line cycles on and off will be dimmer than full on.  However, I wouldn't go too far with this.  The lights will not dim linearly, and with various inconvenient in-between brightnesses the repition period will be so long as to be noticeable.  I would design the display for simple on/off control and not try to do dimming except maybe 1/2 way.

The reason you don't want a variable resistor for dimming is that it will dissipate a lot of power.  The power something takes is the voltage accross it times the current thru it.  A switch or relay is always full on or full off.  When fully off, there is no current so no power lost.  At full on there is no voltage accross the relay, so again no power lost.  Let's say your lights draw 1A at 110V for 110W.  That means at full on they appear like a 110V / 1A = 110Ω resistor when on.  If you put another 110Ω resistor in series with the lights (and assume for now the lights continue to look like a 110Ω resistor), then each drops half the voltage.  There is now twice the total resistance accross the line, so the current will be half what it was before, or 500 mA.  That means a total of 55W will go somewhere.  In this case half of that goes to the lights and half of that will heat the resistor.  That's very inefficient.

In practise, the apparent resistance of incandescent lights goes down with lower voltage.  That is because the resistivity of the fillament material changes with temperature.  Since incandescent lights work on creating a high enough temperature so that it glows, the temperature difference, and hence the resistance difference can be large (several times less when cold).  However, the math about a variable resistor dissipating power is still valid.  That's why you want to rapidly switch (called PWM, Pulse Width Modulation) instead of using a true variable resistance to achieve dimmin.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I knew that PWM could be used for sound, no idea that it could be used for lights. I'm going to guess the frequency of the PWM in this case should 0 - 30hz? Probably will get that through trial and error. Thanks Olin!

Comment: Although you answered the OP's fundamental question, I would be interested in knowing if there are digitally controlled potentiometers that can be controlled by a smaller digital VCC than their resistor side voltage. Most commercial digital pots can only handle voltages to VCC->VSS across the actual potentiometer part, necessitating large +/- supplies in certain applications.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you probably are thinking of controlling the brightness of the lights with your arduino. If that's the case, you want to investigate pulse width modulation (PWM), which as luck would have it, is also something the arduino can do. The reason being that using resistive control, you will waste a lot of power, and generate a lot of troublesome, unwanted heat, whereas PWM is much more efficient.

PWM control over lights of that sort would entail using a switching element, and could be accomplished a couple of different ways. However, with the popularity of the arduino these days, I'd be surprised if there isn't a 'shield' for that.

Comment: Haha I am fairly new to electronics and I don't think shields are the most fun way to approach issues =) I do appreciate that I paid $30 for a easily programmable processor and tiny power supply!

Answer (score 0):

If the Christmas lights are incandescent, you could use a 120V dimmer, which is based on a triac (a type of switch) and uses a variable resistor (potentiometer) to control for how much of each cycle the triac stays on -- a form of pulse-width modulation (PWM).  And then you could remove the original variable resistor and replace it with a photoresistor, glue an LED to the photoresistor, enclose this glued pair inside something opaque, and drive the LED using a PWM method (toggling the LED power pin on from 0 to 100% of the time) from your microcontroller.  But whether this can work depends on how much power the dimmer requires its variable resistor to handle, which is determined by the series resistances: P = V*V/(R1+R2) where V = 120 Volts.  Most photoresistors can handle only about 1/8 of a watt.  You can reduce the power dissipated in these resistors by proportionally increasing the resistance both of the variable resistor and of the other resistor in series with it (which together form a voltage divider). But then you would need to proportionally decrease the capacitance (because  C works with R to create the R*C time constant that determines the pulse width) and that would proportionally reduce the gate current at the triac, so you may need to change the triac as well, for one whose gate can be activated by a porportionally smaller current.

You could study basic electronics principles, and then the theory of operation of triacs and AC dimmers. But please don't build or open up any AC power circuits until you know what's dangerous and how not to get hurt.

Or you could look into products such as PowerSSR Tail and its sibling product that detects zero-crossings.  These enclose all the high-voltage parts in plastic and the only wiring you have to deal with is low-voltage wiring that you can connect directly to your microcontroller.